# how to iterate through a CSV file and write to another file in JSON only the csv rows with a certain value?

Tags: json, python-3.x, csv, read-write

I'm trying to take a csv file and iterate through it and only take the lines that have a category of blue and writing those to a JSON file. So far I have created a program that takes all the csv lines and writes to the JSON file. I'm not quite sure how to select only certain csv lines with a certain value.
Here is that program with this output

```
import csv
import json


def csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath):
    jsonArray = []

    with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf:
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf)

        for row in csvReader:
            jsonArray.append(row)

    with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf:
        jsonString = json.dumps(jsonArray, indent=4)
        jsonf.write(jsonString)


csvFilePath = r'csv_example.csv'
jsonFilePath = r'reader.json'
csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFileP
```

output:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "category": "blue",
        "password": "hi"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "category": "red",
        "password": "no"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "category": "blue",
        "password": "lol"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "category": "yellow",
        "password": "yo"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "category": "yellow",
        "password": "sup"
    },
    {
        "id": "6",
        "category": "orange",
        "password": "hello"
    },
    {
        "id": "7",
        "category": "blue",
        "password": "yeah"
    }
]
```

Take this csv file for example

```
"id","category","password"
"1","blue","hi"
"2","red","no"
"3","blue","lol"
"4","yellow","yo"
"5","yellow","sup"
"6","orange","hello"
"7","blue","yeah"
```

How would I make it so only the lines that have a category of blue be written to the JSON file. I've tried

```
if row.category == 'blue'
```

but that clearly won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each line is converted to a python dict by the DictReader you only need to extend your code at one position.

```
for row in csvReader:
   if row["category"] != "blue":
      continue
   jsonArray.append(row)
```

The line `if row["category"] != "blue":` checks if the value of the key category in the row is not blue.
If the line is not blue the code will `continue` with the next row

Comment: Sweet and simple - exactly what I was getting after, thanks